# Why is gdb aborting when I try to print a cosine?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb

Here's my interaction with it. I first start gdb, set a breakpoint, run the program gdb halts at the breakpoint. Then:

```
<code>
(gdb) b 89
Breakpoint 1 at 0x18cc: file parseGaia3DataToSqDeg.c, line 89.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /sixTB/astro/catalogs/gaia3/shSqDeg/fj 

Star 0.0281655 -89.857 not found in 0 tries.

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe5c8) at parseGaia3DataToSqDeg.c:89
89          exit(0); //TEST
(gdb) p cos(.333)
Abort
</code>
```

Gdb simply quits, and I'm back at my command line.

Data on gdb:

```
gdb --version
GNU gdb (Debian 10.1-1.7) 10.1.90.20210103-git

My machine:

               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            27Gi       3.1Gi       1.2Gi       123Mi        23Gi        23Gi
Swap:          976Mi       3.0Mi       973Mi
CPU family: 25
AMD Ryzen 5 5600G with Radeon Graphics
CPU MHz: 1397.031
CPU max MHz: 5000.6831
CPU min MHz: 1400.0000
BogoMIPS: 7784.71
CPU cache size: 512 KB
No brand USB OPTICAL MOUSE 
Microsoft Corp. Microsoft Ergonomic Keyboard

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             14G     0   14G   0% /dev
tmpfs           2.8G  1.5M  2.8G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2  233G   22G  199G  10% /
tmpfs            14G     0   14G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p1  511M  3.5M  508M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb1       3.6T   93G  3.4T   3% /fourTB
/dev/sda1       5.5T  2.3T  2.9T  45% /sixTB
tmpfs           2.8G  132K  2.8G   1% /run/user/1000
```

FWIW, in previous versions of gdb, I could always print a cosine or other math function.

Comment: Does this happen with all programs? I suspect something in this program has corrupted the heap.

Comment: I got `(gdb) p cos(.333)`
`Aborted (core dumped)` from `gdb` itself :-)

Comment: If you are having a problem with your code, it's quite important to show the code.

Comment: I managed to fix it by installing/updating all the `debuginfo` packages needed for the current binary. My gdb lists the missing `debuginfo` packages when it reaches the breakpoint. Now when I've installed/upgraded those packages, `p cos(.333)`  works fine. In Fedora, just running `dnf upgrade` will not automatically upgrade the debuginfo packages so I do `dnf upgrade --enablerepo '*-debuginfo' --refresh -y`

Comment: Ted's post pointed me in the right direction. It seems that the Debian team has configured their gdb download to not include most of the tools required for serious debugging. To get the full download in Debian or Ubuntu, use this command (from root):  apg-get gdb gdb-doc build-essential devscripts

Comment: Note the above download command is useful for Linux systems that use apt-get for installing software. For the RedHat world use Ted's suggestion.

Comment: Please write an answer or delete the question. Visitors don't expect solutions in comments. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

OK, the above comment's solution worked once, and then quit. cos(.333) aborted gdb. Oh well... I'm wondering if it's a gdb or Debian problem, or that my machine's hardware is simply weird. I also neglected to include in the above comment's command "install" The command should read:

```
apg-get install gdb gdb-doc build-essential devscript
```

Comment: I've had similar problems (but in Fedora) earlier. I've had to enable the debuginfo repos explicitly - or they get "old" when the original libraries are upgraded and strange things happens. Perhaps there's some way to enable keeping all the dev/debug stuff in sync with the libraries on Ubuntu too. This _should_ be a common source of confusion for devs working on Ubuntu otherwise :-)